# What channels does the xbee use to communicate?

Tags: xbee, zigbee, node-xbee

I have some XBee3 pro, I made a network, a coordinator and 7 routers or end devices, the coordinator sends a broadcast (DL = 0xFFFF) to all the routers so that they receive the information, in the same way of some routers that need to send information, too I do a broadcast. My doubt arises in which channels the communication works, since where I will place these devices they have a system that works on channels 25 and 26 and I would not want to interfere with those channels.

What channels are used for communication between xbee's?

Is it only one channel that is used or are there several?

Is this channel fixed or are they dynamic?

Is there a fixed channel by default in which the xbee works?

In case those channels (25 & 26) are being used, how could I block those channels in the XCTU so that they are not used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ATSC` configures the channel mask, and `ATCH` reports the channel currently in use.

This [Zigbee Channels](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001537/references/r_channels_zigbee.htm) document from Digi does a good job of explaining how to configure `SC`.  A value of 0x3FFF would mask off channels 25 and 26 and enable all other channels.

Comment: Hi @tomlogic, It is enough to put (DL = 0x3FFF), or is it necessary to do something else? I understand that a default channel will be used in the coordinator, verifying which one it is, and if it is not 25 and 26, is it necessary to put 0x3FFF anyway?

Comment: `ATSC=0x3FFF` on the coordinator will ensure it doesn't establish a network on channels 25 and 26.  The `ATSC` setting on routers limit the channels they will search for a network to join.